# Rails 4 Model Categories and Multiple SubCategories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create in Rails 4 a model with Subcategories for school lessons :

There are 3 models :
- Category
- Topic
- Level

Categories are for instance: Sciences, Languages, Test Prep, won't be more than 15~20.
Topics are for instance: Mathematics, Physics, English, Spanish, won't be more than 30~50.
Levels are for instance: High School, Graduate Studies, won't be more than 5~7.

**First Approach:**

Create 3 separate models and add the relations

```
Category has_many :topics
Level has_many :topics
Topic belongs_to :category
Topic belongs_to :level
```

**Second Approach**

Create 2 tables: Category and Topic, Category is the same as above, Topic holds the levels in the same table as nested subcategories. Parent topic is Mathematics, child topic is Mathematics - High School.

```
Category has_many :topics
Topic belongs_to :category
Topic has_many :subtopics (parent_id foreign key)
SubTopic belongs_to :parent_topic
```

The first approach was my initial thought, but 3 different models to handle the situations seems a lot. Any recommendations for this kind of situations?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to do it progressively. Start with the fewest which is level at the top.

```
class Level
 has_many :categories
 has_many :topics,:through=>:categories
end
class Category
 belongs_to :level
 has_many :topics
end
class Topic
 belongs_to :Category
end
```